# Cranking engine with coil wire removed - damage?

Tags: electrical, ignition-coil, distributor

I cranked the engine while the wire connecting the coil to the distributor was removed in order to not spark the engine.

Apparently this is not the right way to do it. Have I caused some damage by doing this?

Comment: How much cranking did you do?

Comment: Two times maybe 4 seconds.

Comment: Never damaged one doing what you did, best solution is to ground the coil lead after it is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I would disconnect the supply to the coil, but it does depend on which coil / ignition system is fitted.

If it is the older type non electronic then it will be fine.

However any of the electronic types can suffer damage sometimes but not always.

After building an engine I would spin it without plugs and the coil disconnected to get the oil circulated and the pressure up then fit plugs and fire up.

Comment: The distributor is electronic, but i think otherwise it's "old fashioned". And there was no power from the coil to the distributor.

Comment: That "power from the coil to the distributor" is the high voltage which I suggest avoiding by disconnecting the supply to the coil...